# Windows service to do job every 6 hours

Tags: c#, .net, rest, windows-services

I've got a windows service with only two methods - one private method `DoWork()`, and an exposed method which calls `DoWork` method. I want to achieve the following:

- Windows service runs `DoWork()` method every 6 hours
- An external program can also invoke the exposed method which calls `DoWork()` method. If the service is already running that method called from the service, `DoWork()` will again be invoked after the current method ends.

What's the best approach to this problem? Thanks!

Comment: For communication with a service from an external program, use a web service. For triggering a method to run at a given time interval, use a `System.Timers.Timer` instance.

Comment: Windows comes with a scheduling service. Don't reinvent the wheel, use the scheduling service.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If the purpose of your application is only to run a specific task every six hours, you might be better off creating a command line application and creating a scheduled task that Windows runs automatically. Obviously, you could then manually start this application.

If you're still convinced you need a service (and honestly, from what I've seen so far, it sounds like you don't), you should look into using a Timer, but choose your timer carefully and read [this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc164015.aspx) to get a better understanding of the timers built into .NET (Hint: Pay close attention to [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx)).

To prevent reentry if another method tries to call DoWork() while the process is in the middle of performing its operation, look into using either a [Mutex](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.mutex.aspx) or a [Semaphore](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.semaphore.aspx).

Answer (score 7):

An alternative approach would be to make use of a console application which can be scheduled by Windows task scheduler to run every 6 hours. In that case you don't waste resources to keep the Windows service running the entire time but only consume resources when needed.

For your second question: when you take the console app approach you can have it called by making use of [Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) for example.

Comment: How do I check if the process is already running, and if it is, wait until it finishes and then do Process.Start to run it again? EDIT: Just saw the answer in senfo's post.

Answer (score 3):

there are benefits and drawbacks either way.  my inclination with those options is to choose the windows service because it makes your deployment easier.  scheduling things with the windows task scheduler is scriptable and can be automated for deployment to a new machine/environment, but it's still a little more nonstandard than just deploying and installing a windows service.  you also need to make sure with task scheduler it is running under an account that can make the webservice call and that you aren't going to have problems with passwords expiring and your scheduled tasks suddenly not running.  with a windows service, though, you need to have some sort of checking in place to make sure it is always running and that if it restarts that you don't lose hte state that lets it know when it should run next.

another option you could consider is using nservicebus sagas.  sagas are really intended for more than just scheduling tasks (they persist state for workflow type processes that last for more than the duration of a single request/message), but they have a nice way of handling periodic or time-based processes (which is a big part of long running workflows). in that a saga can request that it get back a message from a timeout manager at a time it requests.  using nservicebus is a bigger architectural question and probably well beyond the scope of what you are asking here, but sagas have become how i think about periodic processes and it comes with the added benefit of being able to manage some persistent state for your process (which may or may not be a concern) and gives you a reason to think about some architectural questions that perhaps you haven't considered before.

Answer (score 2):

you can create a console application for your purpose. You can schedule the application to run every 6 hours. The console will have a default method called on application start. you can call your routine from this method. Hope this helps!!